# How to get the MD5 fingerprint for an RSA public key on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, rsa, md5, public-key

**Preamble:** Working with Android Studio and pushing my "Hello World" app to the phone, I was presented with a confirmation dialog like this:

> Allow USB debugging?
>
> The computer's RSA key fingerprint is:
>
> `<some_md5_fingerprint>`
>
> [] Always allow from this computer
>
> CANCEL OK

Although I was quite sure it was my machine trying to connect, I asked myself how I would confirm that.

This sprang two more **concrete questions:**

- Where is the RSA public key?
- How do I get the MD5 fingerprint for an RSA public key?

Additionally, I wanted a widely usable answer so the solution should be available to every Windows (win7 in my case) user without requiring installation of software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using `cmd` and its `for` loop as well as `certUtil` which should all come pre-installed.

Open `cmd` by

- pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `cmd` then confirming, or
- opening Windows' Start menu, searching for `cmd.exe` and executing.

**TLDR**

```
for /F "tokens=2" %a in (id_rsa.pub) DO (echo %a) > tmp.key_base64
certUtil -decode tmp.key_base64 tmp.key_bytes
certUtil -hashfile tmp.key_bytes MD5
```

**Where is the RSA public key?**

Usually the keys are kept in the directory `.ssh` under the user's home.

(Android Studio stores different(!) keys, `adbkey.pub`, in the directory `.android` under the user's home and in its installation directory, here `C:\Android\.android` - both keys were issued to the phone during the process mentioned in the preamble above.)

After opening the console you should already be in your home directory and only need to change into `.ssh`

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%>cd .ssh
```

In case you're not in your home directory type

```
cd \Users\%USERNAME%\.ssh
```

and execute.

(For Android Studio change directory to `\Users\%USERNAME%\.android` or `\Android\.android` respectively.)

**How do I get the MD5 fingerprint for an RSA public key?**

For this I needed to know that the actual key in the file is the base64-encoded part, i.e. the [long cryptic string of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples). In my cases the *key field* was always followed by a *user-host field*, i.e. a string like `user@domain.com` (also `unknown@unknown`) and in some cases preceded by a field containing `ssh-rsa`.

In those latter cases I needed to filter the second field. In windows, apparently, this is done using a `for` loop. I also send the output to a file for subsequential digestion by `certUtil`, its output again brought into a file - containing the key no longer base64-encoded but in bytes - which is finally hashed using MD5.

Extracting the key which is in the second field of my `id_rsa.pub` to a file named `tmp.key_base64`:

```
for /F "tokens=2" %a in (id_rsa.pub) DO (echo %a) > tmp.key_base64
```

(First field for Android Studio's `adbkey.pub`: `"tokens=1"`)

Base64-decoding to receive the actual public key in file `tmp.key_bytes`:

```
certUtil -decode tmp.key_base64 tmp.key_bytes
```

Hash the key using MD5:

```
certUtil -hashfile tmp.key_bytes MD5
```